AttributeError: type object 'lexer' has no attribute 'current_character'
class lexer:
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self.position = -1
        self.current_character = None

    def advance(self):
        self.position += 1
        self.current_character = self.code[self.position] if self.position < len(self.code) else None

    def generate_list(self):
        tokens = []

        while self.current_character != None: ###AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current_character'
            if self.current_character in ' \t':
                self.advance()
            elif self.current_character in digits:
                tokens.append(self.generate_number())
            elif self.current_character == '+':
                tokens.append(token(plus))
                self.advance()
            #(Other tokens...)
            else:
                errant = self.current_character
                self.advance()
                return [], errors.m1(position, errant)

        return tokens, None

Inside generate_list() method, Python doesn't recognize any of methods I write under 'self.' class and throws the same error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '(...)'
I've tried putting brackets after self.current_character, like self.current_character(), but the interpreter blamed only the 'self.current_character' part and threw the same error, ignoring the brackets. I've also tried replacing self with lexer but it didn't recognize lexer.

The error is telling you that self is a str object. If I had to guess, the code elided by #(Other tokens) has something like self = ... where you intended to assign to an attribute of self instead.
